finding a min point of a function using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
I would like to know why the next state holds true:
$$
\min  \| y \|  +a^T y= 
\displaystyle  \begin{cases} 
 0, & \text{if }\|  a \| \leq 1 \\  
 - \infty, & \text{if }\| a \| > 1 \\  
 \end{cases} 
$$
$\text{So far, I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and I showed that  when }$ $  \| a \| \leq 1 $
$$
- \| y \| \leq -\| a \|  \|  y\| \leq a^Ty
$$
How can I proceed from here?
Thanks!

You can use calculus. The stationarity condition for $y \neq 0$ is $\frac{y}{|y|} = -a$. Check the value of $f$ at the solutions to the stationarity condition. Check the boundary cases $f(0)$ and $f(|y| \to \infty)$, and you are done.

The $\infty$ should be $-\infty$. Please fix it. Also, note the MathJax changes.

You can use Cauchy-Schwarz for one of the conditions.
Let $f(y) = \|y\| + a^T y$, it is clear that $f(0) = 0$ and so $\inf_y f(y) \le 0$ always.
Since $\|y\| + a^T y \ge \|y\| - \|a\| \|y\| = (1-\|a\|)\|y\|$, we see that if $\|a\| \le 1$ then $\inf_y f(y) =0$.
If $\|a\|>1$, then for $t \ge 0$, we have $f(-ta) = t (\|a\| - \|a\|^2) $ and so $\inf_y f(y) = -\infty$.

u are the best!
